# Data frame Merge in a specific format

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-2.7

I have two dataframe, and i am able to merge it. but I want to merge it in specific format ( column wise), Below are the further details

```
>df1

  id        A        B       C
0  1        20       0       1
1  2        23       1       2


>df2

  id        A        B       C
0  1        10       1       1
1  2        20       1       1
```

Below is my code and output

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='id',suffixes=('_Pre', '_Post'))
```

The output of this is :

```
  id       A_Pre    B_Pre   C_Pre   A_Post   B_Post  C_Post
0  1        20       0       1      10       1       1
1  2        23       1       2      20       1       1
```

But the EXPECTED output should be, Can someone help or guide me for this :

```
  id       A_Pre    A_Post   B_Pre   B_Post   C_Pre  C_Post
0  1        20       10       0       1       1       1
1  2        23       20       1       1       2       1
```

Comment: `sort_index(axis='columns')`

Comment: @ifly6 Note the `Pre` and `Post`, `"o" < "r"`.

Answer (score 0):

When subsequently manipulation is possible you can do domething like:

```
df[np.array([[x+"_Pre", x+"_Post"] for x in df1.columns.drop("id")]).flatten()]
```

Comment: this worked but dropped the id column so instead I used sort_index(axis='columns')

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to modify the order of your columns you can use reindex :

```
df = df.reindex(columns=['A_Pre','A_Post','B_Pre','B_Post','C_Pre','C_Post'])
```

Answer (score -1):

You can order the columns in the new dataset using sorted and just add the column "id" in a second statement

```
order_col = sorted(df.columns[1:], key=lambda x:x[:3])  
df_final = pd.concat([df['id'],df[order_col]], axis=1)
```

Comment: The answer should be generalize as this is not a specific problem. There are a lot better and easier ways available.